# PHP Stuck on comparing strings to arrays and activating a function

Tags: php, arrays, function, sms, response

Ok, I am trying to create a somewhat dynamic sms auto-responder with PHP.  Right now, I have a basic one up and running which can respond to single word inputs.  See here:

```
<?php

/* Include twilio-php, the official Twilio PHP Helper Library,
 * which can be found at
 * http://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries
*/

include('Services/Twilio.php');

/* Controller: Match the keyword with the customized SMS reply. */
function index(){
    $response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();
    $response->sms("Reply with one of the following keywords:
monkey, dog, pigeon, owl.");
    echo $response;
  }

function monkey(){
    $response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();
    $response->sms("Monkey. A small to medium-sized primate that
typically has a long tail, most kinds of which live in trees in
tropical countries.");
    echo $response;
}

function dog(){
    $response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();
    $response->sms("Dog. A domesticated carnivorous mammal that
typically has a long snout, an acute sense of smell, and a barking,
howling, or whining voice.");
    echo $response;
}

function pigeon(){
    $response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();
    $response->sms("Pigeon. A stout seed- or fruit-eating bird with
a small head, short legs, and a cooing voice, typically having gray and
white plumage.");
    echo $response;
}

function owl(){
    $response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();
    $response->sms("Owl. A nocturnal bird of prey with large
forward-facing eyes surrounded by facial disks, a hooked beak,
and typically a loud call.");
    echo $response;
}

/* Read the contents of the 'Body' field of the Request. */
$body = $_REQUEST['Body'];

/* Remove formatting from $body until it is just lowercase
 characters without punctuation or spaces. */
$result = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/u", " ", $body);
$result = trim($result);
$result = strtolower($result);

/* Router: Match the ‘Body’ field with index of keywords */
switch ($result) {
   case 'monkey':
        monkey();
        break;
    case 'dog':
        dog();
        break;
    case 'pigeon':
        pigeon();
        break;
    case 'owl':
        owl();
        break;

/* Optional: Add new routing logic above this line. */
    default:
        index();
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to get this to respond if someone texts in something like "Hey, is that dog for sale?".  As of right now, it only works if the word 'Dog' or 'dog' is texted.

I've been messing with arrays, preg_match, stripos/ strpos, but cannot for the life of me make it function correctly.  Can anyone help with at least pointing me in the right direction?  I'm in the process of learning to code to fix my own problem because there were none available, so bear with me that I'm new at this.  Thanks!

Ok, so here's what I've got now,  (which doesn't work) but I think is on the right path.  This is just swapped into the above code, and is not the entire code:

```
/* Read the contents of the 'Body' field of the Request. */
 $body = $_REQUEST['Body'];

 /* Remove formatting from $body until it is just lowercase
characters without punctuation or spaces. */
 $result = rtrim($body, ", . ! ?");
 $result = strtolower($result);
 $result = explode(' ', $result);
 $keyword = array('dog', 'pigeon', 'owl', 'monkey');
 $testword = array_intersect($result, $keyword);
 print($testword);


/* Router: Match the ‘Body’ field with index of keywords */
switch ($testword) {
    case 'monkey':
        monkey();
        break;
    case 'dog':
        dog();
        break;
    case 'pigeon':
        pigeon();
        break;
    case 'owl':
        owl();
        break;

/* Optional: Add new routing logic above this line. */
    default:
        index();
}
```

Comment: What should the script do if someone texts with a message that contains much more words than just "dog"? What should happen if the message contains for example "dog owl dog"?

Comment: You need to look for the string inside $result, you are currently testing for exact matches in your switch statement. Change it to find the words you are looking for with $result - you are on the right track with preg_match.

Comment: Ideally, what I'd like is that if someone texts in a message with more words than just dog, or owl or whatever it just picks out the keywords, and responds to those appropriately.  Don't worry about the multiple keywords, as I want to get it working first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are various ways to do this. Here is my suggestion:

First, don't remove the spaces from the user input. If you just have one long string with no spaces, it's possible to get false matches because of stuck-together ends/beginnings of words that happen to form a string you're looking for.

Instead, after you've removed the other characters and converted to lowercase, convert `$result` to an array of words by splitting the string on space.

```
$result = explode(' ', $result);
```

Then, compare that to an array of the names of your functions using array_intersect.

```
$keywords = array('monkey', 'dog', 'pigeon', 'owl');

$matches = array_intersect($result, $keywords);
```

Any matches will correspond to functions you have defined, so you can call them like this:

```
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $match();
    break; // or don't break, depending on what you want to do with multiple matches
}
```

Comment: I see exactly what this is trying to do, but when I put it into the block it doesn't seem to work.  I'm sure I didn't integrate it correctly though.

Comment: Hmm, I tried to include just the important pieces in the answer rather than integrating it into the rest of your code. I'm confident the concept works, anyway. If you could share your attempt at using it in an online editor (codepad, etc.), I could probably tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: I can try that in just a second, but with your code, would I remove the switch case section entirely?

Comment: Yes, I intended this to be an alternative to that approach rather than an addition.

Comment: Ah, let me try that then.  I feel like I'm making this whole thing harder than it needs to be.

Comment: I feel like that so frequently that I've decided it's just part of the standard path to understanding (at least for me).

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work.  I feel like the explode, then compare arrays is the way to go though.